# Scrapy getting 400 Bad Request in request identical to the browser request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape the price data in the table from this page https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/petrobras-petr4/historico/

The data is requested in a POST request from this URL https://www.infomoney.com.br/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

**POST Form:**

```
{
    "page":"0",
    "numberItems":"50",
    "action":"more_quotes_history",
    "quotes_history_nonce":"2510da6f8d",
    "symbol":"PETR4"
}
```

The `quotes_history_nonce` I'm retrieving from a `<script>` tag in the html, same as the browser's.

```
response.xpath('//script').re(r'quotes_history_nonce":"(\w+)"')
```

I've tried several **combinations of headers**, including a identical copy of my browser headers. (With and without cookies, for testing sake).

**Browser's Headers:**

```
{
    "Accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language":"pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Content-Length":"93",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Cookie":"_omappvp=S4sOqvsk...; _omappvs=159...; tt_c_vmt=159...; tt_c_c=direct; tt_c_s=direct; tt_c_m=direct; _ttuu.s=1593...; tt.u=0100...",
    "DNT":"1",
    "Host":"www.infomoney.com.br",
    "Origin":"https://www.infomoney.com.br",
    "Referer":"https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/petrobras-petr4/historico/",
    "TE":"Trailers",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}
```

Cookies middleware is enabled btw.

The return should be a simple JSON, however I keep getting a 400 return. In my first try I remember getting a CORS block (while simulating in the browser) but can't reproduce it anymore, so perhaps this isn't even related.

If simulating the request made by using the date fields the form gets two new fields:

```
{
    "initialDate":"01/07/2019",
    "finalDate":"01/07/2020",
}
```

Still no luck though. Changing params and resending with the browser works just fine, on scrapy I keep getting 400.
At this point I ran out of ideas. What else I might be missing?

**EDIT**: since my answer for @Booboo adds detail to the question, and also is too long for a comment, I'm editing here.

I expect a JSON as response, because that's what my browser's get from response:
[image]

What I'm looking to scrape is the **data in the table (red box)**, which is loaded from a JSON. As previosly mentioned, the JSON comes from a POST request to https://www.infomoney.com.br/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Just tried using the post params as query params in a GET request as suggested. My browser loads the page, but will only load the data after making the subsequent post request, just as it would without the query params in the url. Scrapy loads the page with **no data in the table**, because it doesn't execute javascript, and the data is dynamically loaded. (That's why I'm requesting the API directly for the JSON)

I'm making requests using scrapy, so here is how:

```
scrapy.Request(url='https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/petrobras-petr4/historico/')
```

and

```
scrapy.FormRequest(url='https://www.infomoney.com.br/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', formdata=form, headers=headers)
```

`form` and `headers` are the same as defined above the edit.

As I mentioned, the headers in the question are **identical to my browser**, so my browser's headers also have `"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"`.

Comment: It is very likely that they are blocking you on purpose. Maybe use selinium?

Comment: I have gotten this to work using the Python `requests` package (see my answer). It might be you have something in your headers it does not like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program does not use scrapy; it is just a plain old Python program that uses the requests package, but it seems to work:

```
import requests

data = {
    'page': '0',
    'numberItems': '50',
    'action': 'more_quotes_history',
    'quotes_history_nonce': '2510da6f8d',
    'symbol': 'PETR4'
}

response = requests.post('https://www.infomoney.com.br/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data=data, headers={'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'})
results = response.json()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[{'display': '03/07/2020', 'timestamp': '1593734400'}, 'n/d', '21,98', '-0,36', '21,80', '22,18', '515,18M']
[{'display': '02/07/2020', 'timestamp': '1593648000'}, '22,10', '22,06', '1,61', '21,86', '22,21', '1,22B']
[{'display': '01/07/2020', 'timestamp': '1593561600'}, 'n/d', '21,71', '0,74', '21,52', '22,25', '1,72B']
[{'display': '30/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1593475200'}, '21,34', '21,55', '-0,51', '21,09', '21,80', '1,39B']
[{'display': '29/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1593388800'}, 'n/d', '21,66', '3,93', '20,93', '21,66', '1,27B']
[{'display': '26/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1593129600'}, '21,21', '20,84', '-2,93', '20,78', '21,47', '1,15B']
[{'display': '25/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1593043200'}, '20,91', '21,47', '2,24', '20,73', '21,47', '988,35M']
[{'display': '24/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592956800'}, '21,49', '21,00', '-3,00', '20,71', '21,56', '1,37B']
[{'display': '23/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592870400'}, '21,22', '21,65', '3,34', '21,14', '22,07', '1,70B']
[{'display': '22/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592784000'}, '21,60', '20,95', '-2,42', '20,90', '21,60', '942,34M']
[{'display': '19/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592524800'}, '22,00', '21,47', '-0,60', '21,22', '22,22', '1,95B']
[{'display': '18/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592438400'}, '21,18', '21,60', '0,75', '21,08', '21,77', '1,22B']
[{'display': '17/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592352000'}, '21,48', '21,44', '0,33', '21,15', '21,85', '1,34B']
[{'display': '16/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592265600'}, '21,56', '21,37', '3,24', '21,17', '21,91', '2,03B']
[{'display': '15/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1592179200'}, '19,81', '20,70', '0,49', '19,54', '21,09', '2,01B']
[{'display': '12/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591920000'}, '20,62', '20,60', '-3,74', '20,10', '21,17', '2,39B']
[{'display': '10/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591747200'}, '21,89', '21,40', '-1,47', '21,00', '21,90', '2,18B']
[{'display': '09/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591660800'}, '22,03', '21,72', '-3,60', '21,64', '22,04', '2,08B']
[{'display': '08/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591574400'}, '22,55', '22,53', '1,95', '22,01', '22,59', '1,82B']
[{'display': '05/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591315200'}, '22,29', '22,10', '3,13', '22,06', '23,03', '2,53B']
[{'display': '04/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591228800'}, '21,39', '21,43', '-0,19', '21,04', '21,78', '2,29B']
[{'display': '03/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591142400'}, '21,86', '21,47', '0,33', '21,41', '21,91', '1,85B']
[{'display': '02/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1591056000'}, '20,75', '21,40', '5,26', '20,60', '21,40', '1,59B']
[{'display': '01/06/2020', 'timestamp': '1590969600'}, '20,15', '20,33', '-0,05', '20,00', '20,56', '1,75B']
[{'display': '29/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590710400'}, '19,55', '20,34', '2,88', '19,30', '20,34', '2,53B']
[{'display': '28/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590624000'}, '19,69', '19,77', '-0,80', '19,45', '20,08', '1,27B']
[{'display': '27/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590537600'}, '19,80', '19,93', '1,32', '19,15', '19,93', '1,45B']
[{'display': '26/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590451200'}, '19,98', '19,67', '0,98', '19,33', '20,09', '1,35B']
[{'display': '25/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590364800'}, '19,48', '19,48', '4,34', '19,26', '19,56', '731,22M']
[{'display': '22/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590105600'}, '18,80', '18,67', '-2,71', '18,35', '18,90', '1,28B']
[{'display': '21/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1590019200'}, '19,50', '19,19', '-0,57', '19,07', '19,77', '1,57B']
[{'display': '20/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589932800'}, '19,09', '19,30', '3,32', '19,06', '19,44', '1,43B']
[{'display': '19/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589846400'}, '18,51', '18,68', '0,76', '18,41', '18,93', '1,49B']
[{'display': '18/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589760000'}, '18,10', '18,54', '8,11', '17,92', '18,54', '2,13B']
[{'display': '15/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589500800'}, '17,99', '17,15', '-1,44', '17,15', '18,19', '2,35B']
[{'display': '14/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589414400'}, '17,40', '17,40', '-1,08', '16,72', '17,47', '2,03B']
[{'display': '13/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589328000'}, '18,26', '17,59', '-3,03', '17,52', '18,35', '1,54B']
[{'display': '12/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589241600'}, '18,53', '18,14', '-0,06', '18,13', '18,83', '1,30B']
[{'display': '11/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1589155200'}, '18,30', '18,15', '-1,79', '18,11', '18,93', '1,19B']
[{'display': '08/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1588896000'}, '17,74', '18,48', '5,96', '17,71', '18,58', '1,51B']
[{'display': '07/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1588809600'}, '17,75', '17,44', '0,93', '17,35', '17,87', '1,42B']
[{'display': '06/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1588723200'}, '17,87', '17,28', '-3,68', '17,28', '18,06', '1,18B']
[{'display': '05/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1588636800'}, '17,90', '17,94', '3,22', '17,87', '18,48', '1,36B']
[{'display': '04/05/2020', 'timestamp': '1588550400'}, '17,43', '17,38', '-3,71', '17,18', '17,62', '1,04B']
[{'display': '30/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1588204800'}, '17,98', '18,05', '-0,82', '17,70', '18,42', '1,43B']
[{'display': '29/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1588118400'}, '17,80', '18,20', '5,51', '17,53', '18,48', '1,70B']
[{'display': '28/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1588032000'}, '17,04', '17,25', '4,86', '16,63', '17,25', '1,55B']
[{'display': '27/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1587945600'}, '16,14', '16,45', '3,13', '15,78', '16,53', '1,39B']
[{'display': '24/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1587686400'}, '16,69', '15,95', '-5,90', '15,28', '16,79', '2,56B']
[{'display': '23/04/2020', 'timestamp': '1587600000'}, '17,20', '16,95', '1,19', '16,62', '17,43', '1,61B']
```

Comment: Since my answer would be too big as well I edited the question, please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: My comment is now an answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Manage to make it work with scrapy in first try today. Either I screwed up something yesterday or the page had some down time or something. Either way thank you!